# sIFR can't render capital L on Crayon font -- any ideas?

Tags: sifr

i am experiencing a very strange problem with sIFR. though i have it working across a huge number of different fonts, i can not figure out why it will not render a capital "L" in the TrueType font Crayon. see this for a live example of the problem: http://beta.justinchappell.com/sifr/

please note that this font is complete and that it does indeed include the capital L. i can see the capital L in photoshop, etc., but it will not convert via sIFR for some reason. anyone have any ideas? you would make my day.

thank you for any advice!

-justin

Comment: +1 for the weirdest problem on SO today. 8-)

Comment: Sometimes Flash does that… any luck if you make a static Flash movie containing an L?

Comment: Can you get the font in another format like OpenType?

Answer (score 0):

Two options, it is either the font or sifr.
So use a later / earlier version of sifr or get the font in another format.

Additionally, try setting bold, italic, or any formatting options (it seems sifr has some issues with these sometimes).

Not much help, but in my opinion it is a bug with sifr.

Ryan